# Dynamic Chart Title to show "Product" text

Tags: powerbi, dax

```
Chart Title Product = CONCATENATEX(
VALUES(mttr_m[product]),
mttr_m[product],
", ",
mttr_m[product],
ASC
)
```

So from the above Dax Function I have a list of products I choose from on a slicer. That slicer then changes the title on my line graph depending on what I pick. But before I pick anything the line graph shows all products that I can choose from on the title. Is there a addition I can add to the above Dax function to show "Products" when nothing is selected then when I select a product it changes to that product name/s.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean:

```
Chart Title Product :=
IF(
    ISFILTERED( mttr_m[product] ),
    CONCATENATEX(
        VALUES( mttr_m[product] ),
        mttr_m[product],
        ", ",
        mttr_m[product], ASC
    ),
    "Products"
)
```

Comment: This answered my question thank you